# How do I delete All Messages in RSS Feeds Folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, rss

I have about 250,000 unread emails in my Outlook RSS Feeds folder, at the root level. These emails are not directly related to an RSS Feed and I would like to delete them.

The `Clean Up Folder` and `Delete All` buttons are greyed out for this folder (I assume because it is a special folder?), so that doesn't seem to be an option.

If I open the folder and press Ctrl+a, Outlook crashes, possibly because of the number of emails that it is trying to select.

I wrote a rule to permanently delete all emails from the relevant email address and ran the rule, but it seems to skip the RSS Feeds folder (Again, perhaps because it is a special folder?) certainly it has not deleted any items from within it.

How should I delete this large number of emails from this folder?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is amazingly hard to do, but luckily there is a tool called MFCMAPI that can do it - [Here is the Github](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi/releases/tag/21.0.21127.03).

Once in this tool, having logged, I double clicked the root item and was able to locate the RSS Feeds folder in the Top Information Store folder. I right clicked that and was able to empty the folder. I will never fill it artificially again!